# Landing place for all prometheus alert and warning

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitoring, network-monitoring

I am interested in knowing is there something tool like which keep all Prometheus triggered alert in single place like dashboard from where i can also make link some ticketing(jira) tool etc. so if i have 50000+ server ubuntu servers it will a single place to watch what are alert triggering from that node and create ticket. so according that i can perform further checks.Like

1-> Site 1 has high icmp loss
2-> Node on site 3 has lost icmp connectivity
3-> Node xx on site 5 has mongo service in fatal state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, [Telegraf](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/telegraf/), [Influx](https://www.influxdata.com/products/influxdb-overview/) and [Grafana](https://grafana.com/get/?tab=self-managed).

In short, Telegraf (a small agent written in go) can be configured to watch your critical services, and send metrics to InfluxData. InfluxData OSS is an open source database you can run in your infrastructure to store that data. You can then use Grafana to provide a dashboard showing the status of all the hosts.

There's also cloud services from InfluxData which can alert you via Slack, PagerDuty, SMS or email when an adverse event occurs.

Another option is [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/) which is a well-regarded network monitoring system.

Comment: Thanks for update buddy @popey same can be done with Prometheus? right so what's make big difference between telegraf and prometheus .

Comment: I don't know Prometheus, sorry.